# Docusign webhook callback TimeZoneOffset

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using Docusign's webhook event notification to get info about my envelopes. I'm getting XML back from the service, but I'm trying to convert some the timestamps in the XML payload to UTC. The XML payload includes a `TimeZoneOffset` as an element, i.e.:

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
  ...
  <TimeZoneOffset>-7</TimeZoneOffset>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

What happens if the offset is UTC? Is it just `0` or `+0` or `-0`? Could it ever be something like `+1030`? Do positive values have `+` prepended?

How is this field determined anyway? Is it the last sender's timezone offset?

Answer (score 3):

It is the account wide (or users) timezone. For example, I am in AEST which is UTC+10 and my XML comes through with:

```
<TimeZone>AUS Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
<TimeZoneOffset>10</TimeZoneOffset>
```

In Preferences --> Features if I change my API timezone to Pacific Time (US) then my offset changes to:

```
<TimeZone>Pacific Standard Time</TimeZone>
<TimeZoneOffset>-7</TimeZoneOffset>
```

It's based on UTC and the offset will be 'x' for UTC or ahead and '-x' for behind.

Comment: Still not working even after I set it to: http://imgur.com/bxjwiQl . Still comes thru as Pacific Standard Time. Did I set it in the wrong place?

Comment: Uncheck "let users set own timezone"

Comment: Still doesn't work :( `<TimeZone>Pacific Standard Time</TimeZone><TimeZoneOffset>-7</TimeZoneOffset>`

Comment: Looks like the "Timezone for API" setting isn't available in new. Switch to classic and go to Preferences --> Features and there will be an additional dropdown for API timezone. Set it there and you should be good to go.

Comment: Adding to my above comment, it looks like API timezone is actually being deprecated which is why it's not available in NDSE. I've put in a request to have the offset be based on the Account Timezone settings as opposed to the API Timezone.

Comment: I wrote my own code to convert the timestamps into a python `datetime` object. I just had to make sure how you were sending the `TimeZoneOffset` for UTC & positive time zones

Comment: I am getting TimeZoneOffset as 5 for IST when it should be 5:30. Want to know how does the webhook represent data for minutes. <TimeZone>India Standard Time</TimeZone><TimeZoneOffset>5</TimeZoneOffset>